# Regular expression to match defined length number with leading zeros

Tags: regex

I would like to use a regular expression to match a number with a defined length and leading zeros. For example with number length of 6:

```
"000123" //Match
"002535" //Match
"2654" //No match
"000021" //Match
```

Which regular expression can I use for this?

Comment: `\d{6}` allows for only numbers with 6 digits, regardless of what the digits are.

Comment: So is `123456` a valid match?

Comment: Is `000000` a valid match?

Answer (score 8):

Surely this is the simplest:

```
^0\d{5}$
```

Although not stated in the question as a requirement, to exclude an all-zero input, use a negative look ahead for that case:

```
^(?!0+$)0\d{5}$
```

Comment: +1, duh... Much better than mine (deleting it). But needs anchors.

Comment: @zx81 I've used your idea to post a working regex wich rejects `000000` ;)

Comment: @Bohemian very clever ;) I usually refrain from lookahead and lookbehind in java because their implementations are / were seriously bugged. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

If `000000` is a valid match, use [the answer by @Bohemian♦.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24921356/1078583)

If `000000` is not allowed, used this variation on his answer (and please accept his answer not mine):

```
^(?=0+[1-9])0\d{5}$
```

See the matches in **[the demo](http://regex101.com/r/aP0qH2/2)**.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The lookahead `(?=0+[1-9])` asserts that what follows is any number of zeroes followed by one char that is a 1 or a 9
- `0` matches one zeroes
- `\d{5}` matches five digits
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Your first RegEx matches `000000` as well, since `\d` also matches `0`

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you allow any combination of exactly six (6) digits from 0 to 9, the regex would be

```
^\d{6}$
```

If you only allow five (5) arbitrary digits and at least one leading zero, use

```
^0\d{5}$
```

instead.

If you want to disallow `000000` you need to do lookahead:

```
^(?=\d{6}$)\d*[1-9]\d*
```

And finally, if you want to disallow `000000` and force a leading `0`, use

```
^(?=\d{6}$)0\d*[1-9]\d*
```

Comment: There is a much easier way to disallow `000000`. Simply use it as the first pattern of an or, then capture the other pattern. `^000000$|^(0\d{5})$`